# Drawing a table with horizontal lines and multiline cells

Tags: perl, string-formatting

How do I display like in the following way in a table format?

```
Hostname     HostIPs     DomainName    nameservers    NSIps
```

My data is stored as follows for one row:

```
$hostName, @hostIps, $domainName, @nservers, @nsips
```

hostips, nsservers and nsips are arrays.

For one hostname - multiple hostIps and for one domain multiple nameservers and i have to display it in neatly formatted manner.

I tried using `Text::Table`, but it isn't displaying the way I want.

```
my $tb = Text::Table->new("hostName", "IP Address", "domainName", "nameServers", "IP  addr");
$tb->add ($hostName, @hostIps, $domainName, @nservers, @nsips);
print $tb;
```

I have to display it as:

```
hostName IP Address domainName nameServers IP  addr
host1    ip1.1        domain1    serv1.1       addr1.1   
         ip1.2                   serv1.2       addr1.2  
         ip1.3                   serv1.3       addr1.3
host2    ip2        domain2    serv2       addr2 
          ..                      ..       ..
host3    ip3        domain3    serv3       addr3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include newlines into the cell values:

```
$tb->add($hostName,
         join("\n", @hostIps),
         $domainName,
         join("\n", @nservers),
         join "\n", @nsips
        );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I never knew we could use join inside add method of table.

Comment: @Maxwell Using [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) in this manner is quite mundane in Perl. Just wait until you understand how a [Schwartzian transform](http://google.com/search?q=Schwartzian+transform) works.

Comment: @BradGilbert: Yea I am new to Perl, so it will take time to learn it, and I wont learn until I write it. Yea I did came across Schwartzian transform  when trying to implement sorting of domains and subdomains.Its amazing!

Answer (score 1):

What about [Text::TabularDisplay](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTabularDisplay), [Text::ASCIITable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aASCIITable) or [Text::SimpleTable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aSimpleTable)?

Comment: Can it display multi line for a column ?

Comment: @Maxwell - looks like SimpleTable can.

Answer (score 1):

For [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aTable), you need to `add` rows in a loop:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Table;

my $tb = Text::Table->new("hostName", "IP Address", "domainName", "nameServers", "IP  addr");
for (1 .. 3) {
    $tb->add("host$_", "ip$_", "domain$_", "serv$_", "addr$_");
}
print $tb;

__END__

hostName IP Address domainName nameServers IP  addr
host1    ip1        domain1    serv1       addr1   
host2    ip2        domain2    serv2       addr2   
host3    ip3        domain3    serv3       addr3
```